# ConnectionString "DefaultConnection" was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a MVC 4 web application and have the following `ConnectionString` in my `web.config` file.

```xml
<connectionStrings>
<!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;.... />-->
<add name="MyMvcContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;.... />
</connectionStrings>
```

And I have the modified the default `AccountModels.cs` to use the `ConnectionString` `MyMvcContext`.

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("MyMvcContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

However I still get the error of `ConnectionString` `DefaultConnection` was not found. when executing `\Filters\InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs`. Should I change the line 41 as well? Or should I keep the `DefaultConnection` and change the database, etc?

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just uncomment this line in your web.config:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;.... />
```

I guess you are using the a single database in your application, so you should use the same connection string name in your code.

Comment: Should I change the `Initial Catalog` and `AttachDBFilename` to the same of `MyMvcContect` too?

Comment: @NickW First, use a single connection string name everywhere in your code, then remove the second one. I can't tell you if your connection string is true though.

Answer (score 0):

you must use the base project (web project which calls your end layer) connection string name. I hope in your case your web project is having some connection string name as "X".
but the DAL project dbcontext base is using different connection string name as "MyMvcContext". change this to X. This will work. Always config details will be taken from the base project (conditions applied)