# Code first Add-Migration only picks up changes to existing models not new models

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an ASP.NET MVC EF code first project.  I copied it and made another project from it.  I didn't change any of the namespaces or project names.  I copied the existing DB and made a copy with a different name.  Code first migrations work fine in the original project.  In the new copied project they only pickup changes to existing models like adding new fields or changing field names.  If I try to add a new model class, `Add-Migration` doesn't pick up that change.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781968/ef-data-migrations-wont-detect-changes-when-adding-new-migration) but it didn't work.  I tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/existing-database) and it didn't work.

I've tried to delete the migration history folder and dbo._MigrationHistory table data and recreate migrations using `Enable-Migrations`.  I've tried to delete existing migrations in the migration folder and create another initial migration using `Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges` then `update-database`.  Then add my changes. None of this worked.

Comment: You add a `DbSet()` for the new class in the context?

Comment: Thanks this did it.  It's been a while since I did this and looked over this part.

Answer (score 1):

YOU will need to run **Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations**.

Now say you need to add **Address** table to your database code first:

Create your new model Address

Create your Configuration file, something

```
class AddressConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
{
    public AddressConfiguration()
        : base()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.AddressId);
        ToTable("Address");    

    }
}
```

Add your DbSet and modelBuilder data in your main XYZContext.cs file

**DbSet**

```
public DbSet<Address> Address {get; set;}
```

**modelBuilder**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AddressConfiguration());
}
```

Run update-database via Visual Studio's Package Manager Console, make sure you have selected the correct project from the drop down, this is likely to be a .Repository named project.

Your new table should now exist in your database.

Comment: I didn't need to EnableAutomaticMigrations but the rest of this is what I did, same the comment from @SteveGreen