# Migrations is creating DB alone but not tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm using EF Core 2.2.6-servicing-10079. With several migrations, I'm trying to create a new DB. Once I run update-database it creates the blank DB but doesn't apply migrations and hence no tables are created except the migration table.

Migrations folder has several migrations.

ApplicationDbContext :

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, ILocalizationDbContext
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }        

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        : base(options)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public DbSet<...
```

DBSnapShot:

```
    [DbContext(typeof(ApplicationDbContext))]
partial class ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
{
    protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.6-servicing-10079")
            .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128)
            .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

        modelBuilder.Entity(...
```

Output:

> PM> Update-Database Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10400]
>         Sensitive data logging is enabled. Log entries and exception messages may include sensitive application data, this mode should only
>   be enabled during development.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
>         Entity Framework Core 2.2.6-servicing-10079 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options:
>   SensitiveDataLoggingEnabled MigrationsAssembly=Infrastructure 
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>         Executed DbCommand (22ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]'); Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>         Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]'); Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>         Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
>         FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
>         ORDER BY [MigrationId]; Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20405]
>         No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date. No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date. Done.

Comment: So this is from running `Update-Database`? I assume you've already executed `Add-Migration`?

Comment: @JayJordan With Add-Migration and without that I got the same output for Update-Database command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shaun Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131420/shaun-wilson)'s answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/27895448/362261 has solved my problem.

His answer goes like this:

Doing a "batch clean" solved my problem, suggesting EF was using an old/invalid assembly from a folder other than the currently selected 'solution configuration (e.g. DEBUG)'.

To do a batch clean:

1. Select Main Menu -> Build
2. Select Batch Build...
3. Click Select All
4. Click Clean

Close dialog, rebuild and re-attempt migration.